# ReentrantLock with nested tryLock with different timeouts, what will be the actual timeout?

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

I am trying to create an unfair buffer with two calls

1. Add value to the buffer
2. Empty the buffer

Threads that empty the queue should have **higher priority** them threads that add to the queue.

In case the buffer is full I call the empty method internally to allow the queue to empty.

The basic idea is that the locks on add buffer are limited to **addTimeout** and the locks for empty is **emptyAddRatio * addTimeout**  so add will have higher priority (The assumption is that I have more additions then empty).

```
public class EmptyPriorityBuffer {
private ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock(true);
private long addTimeout = 10;
private long emptyAddRatio = 5;
private int maxSize = 1000;
private LinkedBlockingDeque<Object> buffer = new LinkedBlockingDeque<>(maxSize);

public List<Object> empty() {
    try {
        lock.tryLock(addTimeout * emptyAddRatio, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        ArrayList<Object> result = new ArrayList<>();
        buffer.drainTo(result);
        return result;
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
    return Collections.emptyList();
}

public void add(Object object) {
    try {
        lock.tryLock(addTimeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        if (!buffer.offer(object)) {
            empty();
            buffer.offer(object);
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

**My question:** 
What will happen in the case where the buffer is full.
The current thread acquired to lock with addtimeout, now it asks for a nested lock with **emptyAddRatio * addTimeout** witch is larger then **addTimeout**.
Will the thread be interrupted after **emptyAddRatio * addTimeout**  or **addTimeout**?

Comment: If you want consumer threads to have higher priority, then why don't you simply boost their priorities? `Thread.currentThread().setPriority(...)`

Comment: P.S., I am automatically suspicious of any code that calls `lock.tryLock(...timeout args...)`. IMO, a thread should never keep any `Lock` locked for such a long time that some other thread would _want_ to try it with a timeout.

Comment: Thank you for this comment, I agree.I read the java doc's again and changed my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timeout argument in the re-entrant case won't have an effect as you own the lock already. That is, the call to `add` acquired the lock already (and potentially had to wait for max. `addTimeout` milliseconds. Any further attempt to acquire the same lock will succeed immediately.

Note however that you need to check the return value of `lock.tryLock` in both methods `empty` and `add` to determine whether acquiring the lock actually succeeded or timed out. In the latter case you likely want to abort instead of going ahead.